# Como puedo pasar el valor de una variable a la query?

Tags: php, laravel, html5, variables

Estoy haciendo una página en laravel y livewire, lo que necesito es que un grafico se actualice de manera automatica, dependiendo de los parametros que le entrega livewire, pero, no entiendo como puedo pasarle ese valor para que me genere el gráfico que necesito!
les comparto el código

```
public function mostrarChartNorte()
    {
        $categoriaInforme = 0;
        $categoriaSubInforme = 0;

        if (isset($_POST['categoria']) && !empty($_POST['categoria'])) {
            $categoriaInforme = $_POST['categoria'];
        }

        if (isset($_POST['sub_categoria']) && !empty($_POST['sub_categoria'])) {
            $categoriaSubInforme = $_POST['sub_categoria'];
        }

        if ($categoriaInforme == $_POST('categoria')) {
            if ($categoriaSubInforme == $_POST('sub_categoria')) {
                $grafico = DB::SELECT('select count(dv.cameraIndexCode) cantidad_norte, CURDATE() fecha_norte, vc.nombre nombre_norte, left(right(llave, 6),2) horas_norte
                from detalle_vehiculos dv
                join valorcamaras vc
                on dv.cameraIndexCode = vc.idCamara
                where CURDATE() like date_format(dv.crossTime, "%Y-%m-%d") and vc.camara <= 2 
                group by vc.nombre, CURDATE(), left(right(llave, 6),2)
                order by horas_norte asc');

                return $grafico;
            } else {
                $grafico = DB::SELECT('select count(dv.cameraIndexCode) cantidad_norte, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day) fecha_norte, vc.nombre nombre_norte, left(right(llave, 6),2) horas_norte
                from detalle_vehiculos dv
                join valorcamaras vc
                on dv.cameraIndexCode = vc.idCamara
                where DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day) like date_format(dv.crossTime, "%Y-%m-%d") and vc.camara <= 2 
                group by vc.nombre, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day), left(right(llave, 6),2)
                order by horas_norte asc');
            }
            return $grafico;
        }
    }
```

y por la parte de HTML que es la que se encarga de mostrar

```
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">Seleccione una Categoria</label>
                        <select wire:model="selectedSubCategoria" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" selected>Seleccione Categoria</option>
                            @foreach ($categorias as $categoria)
                                <option id="categoria" name="categoria" value="{{ $categoria->id }}">{{ $categoria->nom_tipo }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    @if (!is_null($selectedSubCategoria))
                        <div class="form-group row card-body">
                            <label for="sub_categorias" class="control-label">Seleccione una Sub Categoria</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select class="form-control" name="sub_categorias">
                                    <option value="" selected>Escoge una sub categoria</option>
                                    @foreach ($sub_categorias as $sub_categoria)
                                        <option id="sub_categoria" name="sub_categoria" value="{{ $sub_categoria->id_tipo_informe }}">
                                            {{ $sub_categoria->nom_informe_tipo }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif
```

Estoy cerca de lograr lo que quiero y no encuentro la forma jajaja, es me enredé muy fácil y quedé atado, si alguien de acá, quien sea, puede ayudarme en encontrar la solución a este problema, se lo agradecería de todo corazón, en serio, de ante mano, muchísimas gracias por su paciencia y por su gran amabilidad por responder este post... y si, estoy tratando de alargar esto y poder publicar este post ajjaja

Answer (score 0):

Pues literalmente yo he hecho esto, (no se si es correcto o valido) pero pues me sirve para lo que lo requiero.

```
let variable = "{{$variablePHP}}";
```

Prueba si te sirve a ti este método

Comment: No me sirvió ese metodo! D: